# Can't get SSL configured for Apache CXF and JAX-RS

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

I'm having trouble getting the configuration right to get my CXF REST client to talk to my CXF server. I get the dreaded javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure. The strange thing is, this configuration worked when we were using CXF for SOAP. Any hints are appreciated.

Here is the server-side configuration:

```
<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
<httpj:engine port="443">
<httpj:tlsServerParameters>
    <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
        <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password" file="cxf.jks"/>
    </sec:keyManagers>
    <sec:trustManagers>
        <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password" file="cxf.jks"/>
    </sec:trustManagers>
    <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
        <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
        <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
        <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
        <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
        <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
    </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
</httpj:tlsServerParameters>
<httpj:sessionSupport>true</httpj:sessionSupport>
</httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>


<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" bus="cxf" address="/" >
<jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <ref bean="policyService"/>
</jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

And here is the client configuration:

```
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http:tlsClientParameters>
        <sec:keyManagers
            keyPassword="password">
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS"
                password="password"
                file="cxf.jks" />
        </sec:keyManagers>
        <sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS"
                password="password"
                file="cxf.jks" />
        </sec:trustManagers>
        <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
            <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
        </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
    <http:client AutoRedirect="true" ReceiveTimeout="0"  Connection="Keep-Alive" />
</http:conduit>
```

This is the flavor of client I'm using:

```
MyRestApi api = JAXRSClientFactory.create(myRestUri, MyRestApi.class);
```

This all works fine in the clear, it's just SSL that's a problem.

Comment: Getting a similar issue... Using javax.net.debug=all in the java command line seems to show us that cxf can't find the truststore/keystore.

Comment: I have discovered you need to import the server cert to your client machine. On linux or OS X:  
  
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias <alias> -file <cert file> -keystore <your_path_to_jre>/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to make sure you have the right settings you can hardcode it (temp.) like this:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
```

then with the output check you can debug more...